# Answer posted after question was put on hold?

Tags: bug, closed-questions

[This question on politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13378/why-did-53-of-white-women-vote-for-donald-trump) was put on hold as "Primarily opinion-based" by user-voting on `2016-11-13 12:02:08`. Yet, an answer was posted 55 minutes later on `2016-11-13 12:57:34`.

How is that possible?